# Postprocessing an Knockout.JS input value

Tags: javascript, input, knockout.js

I have a basic input field with a knockout value:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: mytext"/>
```

However I want to perform som logic to my viewmodel after receiving a value for "mytext".
Initially I thought of some kind of post processing event ala "valueUpdate", but basically I just want to run a function after "enter" og "space" is hit. Do I need to write a new bindingHandler or is there a more straight forward knockout-apropriate way of doing this?

Basically what I´m trying to do is a combination of the jquery/autocomplete/multible and Ryan Niemeyers knockout-sortable example http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/vgXNX .

My  is in the div.container after the div.item, replacing the "Add task", like:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="item" data-bind="sortable:{template:'tagsTmpl',data:myTags, allowDrop:true"></div>
     <input data-bind="value: mytext, event: {keypress: handleKey}"/>
     <!-- Line above replacing this: <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.addTag">Add Tag</a> -->                    
 </div>
```

Comment: Is loss of focus from the field ok as the event trigger?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. It may also be an instance of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please update your question, include more context and code (e.g. actual view model logic, including the "some logic" you would like to use), preferably a repro of your scenario.

Comment: @Wayne, I think I can live with a loss of focus. Basically I want the enter/space to create a new instance of an object - with the text input to be one of the attribute of that new object. The I want to push the new instance onto an ko.observableArray.

Comment: @Jeroen, How is it unclear?
I have an ko.observable in an input-field and wants to do some post processing after space/enter is hit.

Comment: It's unclear what your code looks like, and *why* you need this. With that info and  a minimal repro(preferably include what you've already tried and why those approaches didn't meet your needs) it would be a lot easier to help. Currently there's already 2 answers, and I can think of 5 more that would technically answer the question but may not be helpful to you.

Comment: Does that mean you are trying to implement something like http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple ? (I tend to agree with Jeroen. While my answer solves your request, it does so in a very narrow manner and chances are that you *actually* want something different, something that might already exist.)

Comment: Well, my experience is you critiziced in here if you overcomplicate things. What I´m trying to do is a combination of the jquery/autocomplete/multible and Ryan NieMayers knockout-sortable. I have updated the main Q with some info on this, including @Tomaleks approach below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> basically I just want to run a function after "enter" og "space" is hit.

You could use the `event` binding.

```js
ko.applyBindings({
    mytext: ko.observable("initial value"),
    handleKey: function(data, event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 0x20) {
            console.log("Space has been pressed!");
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="text" data-bind="value: mytext, event: {keypress: handleKey}" />
```

Comment: The event-approach solved my case. Thanx! :)
I added a call to a function to add an tag into the "handleKey"-function which solved my issue. Solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/qbjytqop/

Comment: @AsleG Hint: Use `keyup` instead of `keypress` if you want to catch the cursor keys, too.

Comment: I love hints like that. :D Thanks, @Tomalek!

Comment: FWIW, I have updated your original JSFiddle and improved, well, everything. http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/qbjytqop/29/.

Comment: wow! Thanx. I´m going to study that. Meanwhile I´d taken my original fiddle one step further with adding the initialTags as a set of options for jQuery Ui Autocomplete to the add tag <input>. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/qbjytqop/ 
However it has a bug: when adding a tag by 'enter' or 'tab' or 'r-arrow' it does´t set the value from the autocomplete, solely the typed letter. (try typing 't', cho0se 'Timetravel', push 'enter': it returns a tag with label 't')

Comment: Btw, @Tomalak, like your chosen tag. ;)

Comment: @AsleG I think I've spent enough bonus time with this question, you'll have to move on without me. :)

Comment: I fully understand and I acknowledge your efforts, @Tomalak. Thanks a lot. :)